# Why is the 'book1 ' printed?

Tags: javascript

```
function defineReactive(data, key, val) {
    observe(val); // 递归遍历所有子属性
    console.log(key,val);
}
 
function observe(data) {
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(data,key,data[key])
        defineReactive(data, key, data[key]);
    });
};
 
var library = {
    book1: {
        name: ''
    }
};
observe(library);
```

The above is the code part, and the screenshot below is running. Why does 'book1' print?

[image]

Comment: You're printing `key` which is `book1` at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting keys in `library` object in this line `Object.keys(data)`.
the keys in `library`? it is `book1`. Unless you want to find keys inside `book1` you need to do `Object.keys` for nested object.

**TL.DR**: `Object.keys(obj)` only find keys in the first level.